# Connecting to localhost IE10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fiddler, internet-explorer-10

I have two computers and one is the development computer.. i run fiddler2 on the development computer to be able to connect to the localhost dev server from a remote computer.

when i try to connect to localhost on the 2nd computed that is only the "viewer" of development server. i get site cannot be found, thou i see all connections when i visit ordinary pages like google and yeah google...

any one know the solution to this problem, iam currently running on the view computer win8 with ie10, ohh yeah it work totally find with firefox with a manually proxy setup towards the dev-comp.

Comment: Check proxy settings on IE?

Comment: Ive added the proxysettings and i can see all the request details from the view-computer on the dev-computer, but i cannot connect to http://localhost:3435 to dev-computers server.

so what i can see is that the proxy is working as it should and there is something suspect with IE/WIN8

Comment: Martea I don't see how you can connect to from `view` to `dev` using name `localhost`. With browser on `view` are you trying to access `dev` pages?

Comment: Iam using fiddler as a proxy on the "dev" and on the "view" i connect to the proxy to access the local development server on the "dev" computer. so yeah iam trying to access the localhost on the dev computer.

Comment: localhost from view will not get to dev server, (unless you have tweaked DNS so that localhost === `dev`). Use dev's IP:3435. Maybe I have misunderstood in which case ignore me and I will go away :)

Comment: Which IE version are you using, Desktop IE or Metro IE? If Metro, you need to read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx

Comment: EricLaw: the article brings up the same problem, so i guess that will solve  the problem, i shall try this!